# Are other pirates than the strawhats able to find raftel?

Tags: one-piece

For now we know you need the four `road porneglpyh` to get the location of `raftel`.

- `Big Mom` has one of them.
- Another one is held by `Kaido`.
- The third one is on the moving island `Zou`.
- The location of the last is `unknown`.

So we could say Big Mom and Kaido have `1/4` information about the location of raftel. And we assume the don't share this information among each other. So they are pretty far from finding this island.

Ruffys crew is the only known to know 2 road porneglpyh (made a copy of Big Mom's and the one on Zou), so he has `2/4` of the information.

So Ruffys crew is at moment in the best position to find raftel. **But:** even if an other crew had all the road porneglpyh, they can't read them. How are they supposed to get the information that is written on these stones? Is `Nico Robin` the only way to get the location of raftel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the plot, Nico Robin is hinted to be the only person alive that can read Poneglyphs. This is why the World Government declares her to be a high priority target. [Source from Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Poneglyph#cite_note-2)

That being said, we've seen two other potential ways for Poneglyphs to be deciphered:

- [The Voice Of All Things](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Voice_of_All_Things) is what Roger used to understand the Poneglyphs and reach Raftel. It is known to be an extremely rare ability, but we have already seen a couple of other characters exhibit it, including Luffy. However, the purpose of this ability isn't to read poneglyphs and even those with it may not be able to use it in the same way.
- The [Three Eyed Tribe](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Three-Eye_Tribe) is supposedly able to decipher Phoneglyphs with their third eye. This is why Big Mom had a daughter, Pudding, with a member of the tribe. However, it isn't clear if she will be able to activate this power, since she is a mixed type. We don't really have information on other members of this race, but considering what the World Government did to Ohara, it is possible the three eyes may no longer be around.

So the answer to your question is **yes**, based on the information we have so far, Robin is the only one who can decipher them. Hence it might be true that only the Strawhats can figure it out in the end. However, other pirates can always use underhanded means to get this information from her.